# Why useState() behaves different from expected

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I am building a flip card matching game. At first, I need to shuffle all the cards so the game builds the card layout differently each time.

The problem is that I have a `setInterval()` function to create a timer for the game, which means the `App()` function would run every second interval, so my random cards array would keep reset as a random one each time.

(Also when i click or do some other things which cause the function to run would also reset the random cards)

My `Àpp()` is as follows:

```
const cardsIconArray = [{
icon: (<span className="material-symbols-outlined">
  settings_accessibility
</span>),
flipped: false},{
icon: (<span className="material-symbols-outlined">
  terminal
</span>),
flipped: false},...]

const renderedIconArray = [...cardsIconArray, ...cardsIconArray]

function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;
  while (currentIndex > 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
  }
  return array;
}


function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(
    shuffle(renderedIconArray)
  );
//do something afterwards with the `cards`...
}
```

As i noticed, the `cards` variable would refresh every second as the `App()` reruns, which is not what I want.

So I googled a few samples online and rewrote my code as follows:

```
function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(
    shuffle([...cardsIconArray, ...cardsIconArray])
  );
}
```

And it worked!

But I am a bit confused, I simply moved the `concat` function `[...cardsIconArray, ...cardsIconArray]` inside the `useState()` instead of combining my array beforehand. Why would it be different?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In your first example you are creating the original array once, outside of the component.

in your `shuffle` function:

```
 [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
  array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
```

this mutates the original array and since it executes on each render, `shuffle` reruns on each render. `const [card] = useState(originalArray)` makes `card = originalArray` . Card is same as original array and you are mutating it on each render

In the second example you are recreating new array on each render, `card` state gets the value of the first one. Since you are mutating the new array on each render, `card` value leaves untouched

As a solution instead of mutating the original array in your `shuffle` function you can return a new one.

Also if you pass a function to useState, it will run only once

```
const [card, setCard] = useState(() => shuffle(renderedIconArray))
```

shuffle function will be called only on mount